# Android layout page is black without any colors or images

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to create more LinearLayouts one after another but I have problem that I can see just black page.   What is wrong. Why I can not see images?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/featured_group"
                        android:background="@color/yellow"
                        style="@style/Home_Card_Group">
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/sponsored_topic_header"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:src="@drawable/logo_icon"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:scaleType="centerInside"
                            style="@style/Home_Card_Sponsored_Header" />
                        <ImageView
                            android:background="@drawable/bottom_shadow"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="16.0dip"
                            android:contentDescription="@string/shadow_desc" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
               more LinearLayouts
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

STYLES:

```
<style name="Home_Card_Group">
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
</style>

<style name="Home_Card_Sponsored_Header">
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/default_edge_margin</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">@dimen/default_edge_margin</item>
</style>
```

Comment: is it a black or blank page? In Home_Card_Group style you have `visibility: gone`

Comment: Just a hint: The outer LinearLayout and the RelativeLayout immediately inside are **completely useless** and **performance sucking**. Just copy the xmlns and id to the second LinearLayout and get rid of its parent and grandparent. The layout with `android:id="@+id/featured_group"` has **no specified dimensions**. that could be a problem. `fill_parent` is a **deprecated** attribute: use `match_parent`, instead

Comment: You have set the visibility of layout and image gone
android:visibility="gone"   Remove that from ImageView and LinearLayout. That would be visible.